Part number of this IC marking "R2. 8"
Can anyone please help me define the part number of this part marking "R2. 8" in the picture below?


Could you please put a bigger picture as well to show the IC's surroundings?

Two pins on the right are connected with 2N2222 diodes (one Anode and one cathode). One pin on the top left is connected to GND, and the biggest pin is NC.

It's a Semtech SR2.8 TVS diode array.

I can't find a good picture of the SR2.8, but here is one of the SR3.3 as reference:

(Source: lcsc.com)

Thank you very much
